# How would I go about proving the following statement?

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, collatz-conjecture

For all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $y \in \mathbb{N}$,

$$ Q= \frac{2^x-3^x}{3^x-2^{x+y}}$$

the only time Q is a natural number and odd is when $(x,y)=(1,1)$.

I've been trying to solve this for a while as this equation came out of a simplified case of a problem I am working on but I don't know how to consider all the cases.

I have plotted this in Matlab before and I know that when $x \gg y$ it produces very large negative numbers and when $y \gg x$ the limit goes toward zero. But, there is a "line" when $x$ is slightly greater than $y$ that causes the values become weird and sporadic. The last thing I know is that it is easy to see that the only time Q is positive is when $ y > x \log_2 (3/2)$. What methods and/or ideas would help prove this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I forgot to mention in the orignal post but I already know that the cases of $x=y$, $x \gg y$ and,$y \gg x$ back up this statement, I was asking about how I could go about proving the cases where x and y aren't drastically different, thus causing positive numbers close to natural numbers.

Comment: In my studies I use $N$ for $x$ and $S$ for $x+y$ (thus $B$ for $y$) and $N$ denotes the number of *odd steps* in the Collatz-iteration and $S$ the number of *even steps*. Then $S=\lceil N \cdot \log(3)/\log(2) \rceil$ to have $Q$ positive. When $N$ and $S$ are *convergents of the continued fraction* of $\log(3)/\log(2)$ then $Q$ is very near to integers, and one can assume, that this can be arbitrarily near to integers with increasing $N$ Compare for instance http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/2hochS_3hochN_V2.htm to see examples of such $N$ and $S$

Comment: This looks equivalent to the Collatz conjecture; a famous unsolved problem. It is likely you need to create some metric with measures the distance between your quotient and the number $1$. Also look at the 2-adic extension of the Collatz Conjecture mentioned on its Wikipedia page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the discussion around the Collatzproblem we encounter the OP's formula in similar form:
$$ \Large \begin{array} {} Q&= \frac{2^x-3^x}{3^x-2^{x+y}}\\
 &=\frac{2^x-3^x-2^{x+y}+2^{x+y}}{3^x-2^{x+y}} \\
 &=\frac{2^x-2^{x+y}}{3^x-2^{x+y}}-1 \\
 &=2^x \frac{2^y-1}{2^{x+y} - 3^x}-1 
\end{array} $$
and the conjecture:
$$ x=y=1 \Leftarrow \Rightarrow  Q \in \mathbb Z^+$$ 
The only proof that there is no other positive integer solution, that I know of, is the proof of Ray Steiner (using transcendence-theory) from 1978. Later this proof has been somewhat simplified (better bounds for the involved diophantine approximation have been made available) but there has not been found an ***elementary*** way to prove this nonexistence of a positive integer solution for $x,y \gt 1$ . (see an example for that proof at [an older answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2485686/1714) in section "update 2" and also an extraction/ extension focused only at this style of proof [at my homepage](http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_1cycledisproof.pdf).)

Comment: I also found this equation while working on the Collatz Conjecture, I quickly looked at the link you posted so I can say for sure but I believe were approaching it differently so I find it fascinating we both derived this equation. Thank you.

Comment: @Kiyro6 - ah, well, you're welcome! Perhaps you like this: http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz061102.pdf where I arrived at this formula.

Comment: @Kiyro6 - I added a link to my homepage for a small treatize on this style of proof shown (howeve not so simple) by John Simons - see http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_1cycledisproof.pdf