# how to find integer solutions of algebra problem involving division and powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, diophantine-equations

$x = (3^n - 2^n) / (2^{m+n} - 3^n)$

$n$, $m$, and $x$ must be positive integers $\geq 1$

$x$ must also be odd

The trivial solution is

$n=1, m=1, x=1$

Are there any other solutions? If not, is there a way to prove there are no other solutions?

Comment: Rearranging to $(2^{m+n} - 3^n)x = 3^n-2^n$ and testing a couple of low values of $n$ makes it seem improbable that there are other solutions, but I can't rule it out just because $n\leq 8$ doesn't work.

Comment: (This also makes it obvious that $x$ must be odd, even without the problem specifying it; the right-hand side is odd, so the left-hand side must also be odd.)

Comment: Some initial ideas: if $n=m$ then $f(x)=\frac{3^x-2^x}{4^x-3^x}$ is decreasing, so $x(n)<1$ for $n>1$. If $m>n$, $2^{n+m}-3^n>4^n-3^n$, so again $x(n)<1$ for $n>1$. If $m<n$, then $3^n-2^n$ is divisible by $2^m$, but $2^{n-m}$ is an an integer while $(\frac{3}{2})^{n-m}$ isn't so x isn't an integer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How would I go about proving the following statement?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571401/how-would-i-go-about-proving-the-following-statement) - found using an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24x%3D%5Cfrac%7B3%5En-2%5En%7D%7B2%5E%7Bm%2Bn%7D-3%5En%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainteger&p=1). Note there are also other duplicate, or nearly duplicate, questions, e.g., [If $ab > 1$, can $\frac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a}$ be an integer?](/q/4067552) and ...

Comment: (cont.) [Collatz Conjecture: Does it follow that since there is no $1$-cycle, if $ab > 1$, then $\frac{3^a - 2^a}{2^{a+b} - 3^a}$ cannot be an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4067889).