# M and n are positive integers such that $2^n - 3^m > 0$. Prove (or disprove) that $2^n - 3^m \geqslant 2^{n-m}-1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, diophantine-approximation, collatz-conjecture

Given that $2^n - 3^m > 0$, I know that $n > m\log_{2}3$ (*). If $2^n - 3^m \geqslant 2^{n-m}-1$, $n>= m + \log_{2}\frac{3^m-1}{2^m-1}$ (**).

This is the result when I graph it out ($m$ -> $x$, $n$ -> $y$): https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRCu7.png (*) and (**) correspond to the red and blue shaded area, respectively. The inequality could be stated that for $m$, $n$ integers, if $(m, n)$ lies in the red area, it's also in the blue area. In other words, there's no in lattice point in the only-red-shaded area.

The mentioned critical region is bounded by the y-axis (given that $m$, $n$ are positive), the straight line $y_1 = x \log_{2}3$, and the curve $y_2 = x + \log_{2}\frac{3^x-1}{2^x-1}$ that approaches $y_1$ as $x$ approaches infinity (proven using limits). Since $\log_{2}3$ is irrational, $y_1$ does not pass through any lattice point (except at origin), and the distance between $y_2$ and $y_1$ gets smaller and smaller as $x$ gets larger, it is more and more unlikely that the critical region passes through some lattice points when $x$ increases. This support my observation that for large m (say $m=100$), $2^n-3^m$ is not just "larger than or equal" to $2^{n-m}-1$ but EXTREMELY larger ($3\cdot 10^{29}$ times larger in this case)! The gap between the two tends to get bigger as m increases, which makes me believe the inequality is true for all numbers.

For another approach, I see that the inequality has more chance to fail as $n$ decreases and/or $m$ increases; in other words, we just need to take $n$ as a function $n(m)$ equals to the smallest possible number such that $n > m\log_{2}3$. Since $n$ is integer, $n(m) = \lceil m\log_{2}3\rceil$.

Now replace $n$ with $n(m)$ in (**): $$\lceil m\log_{2}3\rceil \geqslant m + \log_{2}\frac{3^m-1}{2^m-1}.$$ Subtract both sides by $\log_{2}(3)m$: $$\lceil m\log_{2}3\rceil - m\log_{2}3 \geqslant \log_{2}\frac{3^m-1}{2^m-1} - m\log_{2}\left(\frac{3}{2}\right).$$ The left side of the inequality is the difference of $m\log_{2}3$ and its rounded-up integer, the right side is the difference of $y_2$ and $y_1$ in the graphing section. Here is the graph of the two: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sxwjY.png Blue and red line correspond to left and right side, respectively; horizontal axis represents $m$. As seen, the left side values jumps back and forth somewhere between $0$ and $1$, while the right approaches zero very quickly (already $0.000175$ at $m=13$), so I hypothesized that the inequality is always true, which would prove the conjecture in my question. However, I have no idea where to go next, since the value of $\lceil m\log_{2}3\rceil - m\log_{2}3$ looks pretty "random" to me; I mean, $m\log_{2}(3)$ is an irrational number (has infinitely many decimal values with no pattern), how can I predict the difference of its rounded-up integer and itself?

By the way, I noticed this inequality while trying to solve the Collatz conjecture, and I'm just curious whether it's really true for all numbers or not (I have checked it with computer for m up to 10 billion). My approach above might be completely wrong, so don't just stick with it. I appreciate any thoughts/suggestions of yours about this conjecture or directions I should go that may help proving this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you tried estimating the area of the critical region. If you can show it small, or reduce to a small area, that would add credibility to your claim that it is unlikely to contain a lattice point. Of course this would not be a proof. (you can compute the part you haven't yet searched).

Comment: No. Unfortunately I don't have the skills to integrate that function, then take the limit of the upper bound to infinity. Anyway as you said, the region's area is unlikely to contribute to the proof, so I didn't bother to learn.

Comment: It might be useful to note that if there are any counter-examples, they must satisfy $$3^m \le 2^n < \frac {3^m - 1}{1 - (1/2)^m}$$Unfortunately, $\frac {3^m - 1}{1 - (1/2)^m} - 3^m$ increases with $m$, so this is not enough to prove the result either.

Comment: In ( https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2485686/1714  // answer to a related problem ) I have an exposition of a proof of a very near question using a result of G. Rhin, which makes the Baker-formula especially effective for that question. For my own training I used it also in 
http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_1cycledisproof.pdf see around eq 3.5. A page showing empirical results for distance of powers of 2 and of 3 up to very high exponents is at
http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/2hochS_3hochN_V2.htm which you might like as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer:** Possible counter-examples must satisfy $m<e^{28}$ and $n<e^{29}$, hence only a finite number of them may exists.
This follows by [Baker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem#Statement) about lower bounds of linear forms of logarithms.

---

For prove it, let $(m,n)$ be a counter example, that's $3^m <2^n <3^m+2^{n-m}-1$.
We get
$$\begin {align}
0 <n\log (2)-m\log (3)
&<\log\frac {1-3^{-m}}{1-2^{-m}}\\
&<\frac {1-3^{-m}}{1-2^{-m}}-1\\
&<2^{-m}
\end {align}$$

By [Baker's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem#Statement) there exists an effective constant $C$ (not depending on $n,m$) such that
$$n\log (2)-m\log(3) >n^{-C} $$
for all $n,m$ such that $n\log (2)-m\log(3) >0$.

This leads to $n^{-C}<2^{-m } $ which implies $\frac m{\log(n)}<\frac C{\log(2)}$ hence $\frac m {\log (n)} $ is bounded by an effective constant.
On the other hand $n\log (2)-m\log (3)<2^{-m}<1$ gives $\log (n)<\log (m)+1$ hence
\begin{align*}
\frac m {\log (m)}
&\leq\frac{3m}{1+\log(m)}\\
&<\frac{3m}{\log(n)}\\
&<\frac{3C}{\log(2)}
\end{align*}

that's $\frac m {\log (m)} $ is bounded as well by an effective constant.

By effectivness of the constant, is enough to verify the impossibility of  $3^m <2^n <3^m+2^{n-m}-1$ for finitely many values of $m,n $.

In particular, the explicit result by [Baker and Wüstholz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%27s_theorem#Statement) states:
\begin{align*}
&\log|\Lambda|>-C'h(\alpha_1)h(\alpha_2)\log(\max\{|\beta_1|,|\beta_2|\})\\
&C'=18(n+1)!n^{n+1}(32d)^{n+2}\log(2nd)
\end{align*}
where $\Lambda=\beta_1\lambda_1+\beta_2\lambda_2$ and in our case
\begin{align*}
&\beta_1=n&
&\lambda_1=\log(\alpha_1)&
&\alpha_1=2\\
&\beta_2=-m&
&\lambda_2=\log(\alpha_2)&
&\alpha_2=3
\end{align*}
hence $h(\alpha_i)=\alpha_i$, $d=1$ and $n=2$.
Since $C=C'h(\alpha_1)h(\alpha_2)$, with these values, we get:
$$C=18\cdot 3!\cdot 2^3\cdot 32^4\cdot\log(4)\cdot 2\cdot 3<8\cdot 10^9$$
from which
$$\frac m{\log(m)}<4\cdot 10^{10}$$
which is satisfied for $m<e^{28}$.
Thus, possible counter-examples are bounded by $m<e^{28}$.
Since $\log(n)<\log(m)+1$ we have $n<e^{29}$, hence only a finite number of counter-examples may exists.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the result by Baker and Wüstholz ?

Comment: Logarithmic Forms and Diophantine Geometry by A. Baker, G. Wüstholz. For the estimate of $C$ I take the formula in the link of Baker's theorem.

Comment: I've been trying to understand this answer for a while, but I still cannot get it.
Specifically, I don't understand the concept around Baker's theorem. How do you get $n\log (2)-m\log(3) >n^{-C}$ for $C=18\cdot 3!\cdot 2^3\cdot 32^4\cdot\log(4)\cdot 2\cdot 3<8\cdot 10^9$? Based on the formulae on the wikipedia page, I can't see the connection of those formulae with the statement above. 
I only have high school level math. Is it too much of a request if I ask you to explain those to me?

Comment: @FelixFourcolor: Added explanation in the answer.

Comment: You mean $\beta_2 = -m$, so that $\Lambda=\beta_1\lambda_1+\beta_2\lambda_2 = n\log(2) - m\log(3)$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @FelixFourcolor:  If I got things correct, then due to a result of G. Rhin (cited in J.SImons 2000) I arrive at $m>96$ (instead of $m>e^{29}$ in this answer) for the OP's equation to hold by the analytic bounds. After that only the cases $m<96$ need be tested individually. See my earlier workout at http://go.helms-net.de/math/collatz/Collatz_1cycledisproof.pdf around pg 3, in particular ineq. $2.4 a$ introducing/adapting Rhin's result.

Answer (score 5):

**Answer:** There are at most finitely many counterexamples. This is related to the [irrationality measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) $\mu$ of $\log 3/\log 2$, which is finite (and effectively boundable) according to [this article by Yann Bugeaud](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01253659/file/38Article4.pdf), Theorem 1.1. What I don't know is whether we can bound the possible counterexamples.

---

We have by the mean value theorem for $\exp$:
$$\begin{align*}2^n-3^m
&\geq 3^m (n\log 2-m\log 3)\\
&\geq 3^m n\log 2 \cdot n^{-\mu-\varepsilon}\end{align*}$$
for (say) $\varepsilon=0.1$, except for possibly a finite number of pairs $(m,n)$ coming from exceptionally good approximations of $\log3/\log 2$.

**To finish,** the idea is that either the inequality is trivial, or $3^m$ is sufficiently close to $2^n$ to show that this is larger than $2^{n-m}$.

Note that (less important)

- $m\leq n-1$ except for small values
- We may ignore the $+1$ in the RHS because the LHS is odd

and more importantly:

- If $2^{n-1} \geq 3^m$ it is trivial, becaue $2^n-3^m > 2^{n-1} \geq 2^{n-m}$

so that we may assume $3^m\geq 2^{n-1}$.

Now $$6^m \geq 6^{(n-1)\log2/\log 3} > 3^{n-1}$$
(use a calculator for the last inequality) so that $$3^m >2^n/2^m \cdot 1.5^n \cdot\tfrac13=2^{n-m}\cdot 1.5^n\cdot\tfrac13$$
where we keep the $1.5^n$ to take care of factors $n^{-\ldots}$.

**Combining everything,**
$$\begin{align*}
2^n-3^m
&\geq 3^mn\log 2 \cdot n^{-\mu-\varepsilon}\\
&>2^{n-m}1.5^n\cdot\tfrac13\cdot n\log 2 \cdot n^{-\mu-\varepsilon}\\
&>2^{n-m}\end{align*}$$
for $n$ sufficiently large (because $\mu$ is finite!), except for possibly a finite number of pairs $(m,n)$.

Answer (score 0):

*I add this comment (not an answer) because you wrote that you tested your conjecture heuristically up to large $m$. I think I provide an interesting further insight.*

---

If you ask for $$2^n-3^m \ge 2^{n-m}-1 $$ we can look at it in another interesting way. But let us first introduce the shorter notation $b=n-m$ . Now let us describe $2^n$ and $3^m$ in terms of $2^b$ where $M$ and the residue $r$ with $0 \lt r \lt 2^b$is formally introduced:
 $$2^b \cdot 2^m-(M \cdot 2^b + r) \ge 2^b-1 \\
    2^b \cdot (2^m-M) -r  \ge 2^b-1 \\
    2^b \cdot (2^m-M)   \ge 2^b+r-1 \\
    2^m-M    \ge 1 + {r-1 \over 2^b}  \\
 $$
 Here the rhs is in the interval $1 \le (\text{rhs}) \lt 2$ We see, that ***only*** for any $M=2^m-1$ this is false if not also $r=1$. Thus the inequality holds, if $M$ is indeed smaller than $2^m-1$. In bitstring-notation this means, if ***there is a zero in the bitstring*** of $M$. This is of course the case in all empirical observations, except for $m=1$ where $b=1$ and $3^1 = M \cdot 2^b + r =  (2^1-1)\cdot 2^1 + 1$ .

The idea of simply looking at the position of the first zero in $M$ is very intriguing and strongly gives evidence for the truth of your inequality. Even the following graph suggests hope that perhaps a functional upper bound of the length of the leading "1"-bitstring might be found.  I've made three images of different resolution. Note, that for my own convenience I used $N$ for what you call $m$ and $S$ for what you call $n$ and $B=S-N$ for what is $n-m$ in your formula.

[image: image1]

And zooming out up to $N=10000$ it suggests there might by a functional bounding for the position of the first occuring zero/for the length of the leading bitstring of "1" (see the read convex hullcurve)

[image: image2]

The hullcurve, btw., matches the positions $N$ which occur in the convergents of the continued fraction of $\log_2(3)$ .
A larger view, only plotting convergents and generalized convergents again suggests a hullcurve which might be convex on the long run:

[image: image3]